# Can't download Eclipse on macOS Catalina

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm having trouble downloading Eclipse on macOS Catalina as whenever I click the downloader, it instantly says "Failed to create the java virtual machine." I currently have java 11.0.6+10 downloaded and I've set it up and everything. I'm able to compile and run a java program from the terminal and IntelliJ also works completely fine. Eclipse works on my old 2014 macbook air so I'm wondering if Eclipse has some conflicts with the newer macOS. I've read some things about java having some security issues with Catalina but I'm not too sure.

Comment: Download from where? Eclipse runs fine on Catalina.

Comment: Please read this forum might help: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/208545/